# Fatal error: Call to a member function field_data(), when moving files to new cluster server

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-datamapper

I'm using a custom CMS that is based on [codeIgnighter](http://codeigniter.com/). Previously it's been running on a [Heart Internet](http://www.heartinternet.co.uk/) server. We are moving to a cluster server with [tsohost](http://www.tsohost.co.uk/).

My code run perfectly fine on the old server (linux, php 5.2, mySQL). I've set up the new server with the same speck (as far as I can tell). I would like to eventually move to 5.3, but for now I just need to get this working without rewriting most of my code, so if you answers can be for php 5.2 it would be more helpful.

Now I get the error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function field_data() on a non-object in /var/sites/p/pplsport.eu/public_html/system/database/DB_driver.php on line 863
```

I've traced the issue back to the following line in my code:

```
$fields = $this->db->field_data($this->table);
```

I've checked to see that `$this->db` exists (which is does), and `$this->table` does refer to the correct table/model.

Here is the site running on the [old server](http://www.pplsport.com), and the [new server](http://www.pplsport.eu).

I'm afraid I've run out of ideas and can't think how to further debug this. If any one could help, that would be great.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you checked the `$this->db` inside the file your are running that command, right?

Comment: In `config/database.php` set `debug` to `TRUE`. Is there an error in a db query?

Comment: so my guess is that your database is lot loaded. Please, when you post a new comment, add the @ symbol before the user name so it gets notified about it ;)

Comment: @Daniel, managed to get the database configured properly now (I had table that was using a reserved name, and so it didn't connect).

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the comments I was able to solve this by figuring out my database settings were wrong.

I set the database `debug` to `TRUE`, and then realized I could not connect to the database.

My table name was using a reserved name, and so it could not be used.

Thanks @Daniel and @Yan